# Build and Run results in an empty window

Tags: unity

Out of nowhere my builds are broken. The .exe just always gives me this little blank window but it runs fine in the editor.

[image]

Here are some things I have tried:

- Deleted the previous build files
- Deleted the Library folder
- Upgraded to 2020.2.4f1
- Uninstalled/Reinstalled Unity
- Deleted AppData Files
- Deleted branch and pulled it back down (the branch works fine for other people)

Here are my resolution and presentation settings:
[image]

Comment: Can you show us your Resolution and Presentation Player settings? Does this also happen if you create a new project from scratch? If so, it's probably a problem with your Unity installation, and you should do a full uninstall and re-install. If it doesn't, try creating a new project, and copying content from your old project into it, testing periodically to see if the problem arises again. If it does, you have a strong clue that something in the last batch you copied is related to this. You can use this to narrow the problem down to a minimal complete verifiable example.

Comment: Interestingly enough...I had someone pull my branch down and the exe works fine. I'm going to try to reinstall unity to see what I can do with it.

Comment: Could be some local preference files got corrupted. Try clearing out any related %AppData% folders or registry keys — they might be storing your last used window dimensions somewhere.

Comment: I uninstalled and reinstalled unity and the issue still happens. I'm not sure if the AppData files would persist through that.

Comment: If they're AppData files for your game, not for the Unity editor, they could.

Comment: Oh ok. Do you have any idea what I should delete? I don't want to delete the wrong files and screw up something else in unity. Do they have a certain naming convention?

Comment: I also noticed that the exe that gets created upon build has a date of 2/9/2021 every time I build it.

Comment: I deleted my project and pulled down the branch again and the exe is still broken.

Comment: This will probably sound dumb but your scenes are listed in the build window right? Not just a bunch of (Scene Missing) messages? It seems possible Unity could have shuffled the GUIDs around when you upgraded to 2020.2.4.

Comment: Yep, the scenes are listed in the build window like normal.

Comment: Have you tried running the exe on a different PC? That should have basically the same functionality as clearing all the app data files and registry keys associated with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was eventually able to solve this issue by clearing the project settings folder in the project. After doing that and setting my scenes back up in the build settings, things seems to work. I kept my TagManager.asset file just so I didn't lose sorting layers, etc.